# Bind default constructor to a std::function<T*()>

Tags: c++

I have a class template which allocates objects and, to allow use of a particular (not default) constructor, an allocation function shall be provided with the following signature to return a pointer to a T object:

```
Foo<T>::Foo(std::function<T*()> allocate);
```

I then implement a function which calls the specific constructor and then bind this method to the `allocate` function:

```
Foo<MyClass> foo( std::bind(&MyClassAllocFunction,parameter) );
```

with `MyClassAllocFunction()` being for instance:

```
MyClass *MyClassAllocFunction( int parameter )
{
    return new MyClass(parameter);
}
```

Now I'd like to use the default constructor, and possibly avoid creating a dedicated function. Is there a way to bind a "default constructor allocator" which would return a pointer to an allocated object ?

***The solution proposed by @MarekR answers my question***

```
Foo<MyClass> foo( []() { return new MyClass {}; } );
```

Comment: You are confusing things here. Allocation functions and constructors are completely independent things. `operator new` returns allocated memory (as `void*`) without any object constructed in it. What is this `std::function<T*()>` supposed to do exactly? It seems to intent to return a pointer to an object, not merely allocated memory.

Comment: where is declaration of `MyClassAllocFunction`? This is important. Also provide [mcve]. Please provide standard of C++ you can use.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/h6YEzTPcb

Comment: @user17732522:  `std::function<T*()>` is supposed to return a pointer to an object. I understand that new only return allocated memory, not an object. So maybe my question should be : is there a default object allocator I can bind to ?

Comment: Example provided by @MarekR solves my question, I edited the question with the answer

Comment: @Mika `new` does create objects, but `operator new` doesn't (except for implicit object createion). These two are different (confusingly named) concepts. `operator new` is an allocation function, `new` is an expression creating objects and potentially calling a allocator function. Neither of them are constructors and a "_default constructor_" also has a specific meaning. It refers to a constructor of a class that can be called without argument.